# Python simple call function from given parameter?

Tags: python

I am learning python, I get this error:

```
getattr(args, args.tool)(args)
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'cat'
```

If I execute my script like this:

```
myscript.py -t cat
```

What i want is print

```
Run cat here
```

Here is my full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(str(sys.argv[0]))
parser.add_argument('-t', '--tool', help='Input tool name.', required=True, choices=["dog","cat","fish"])
args = parser.parse_args()

# Call function requested by user    
getattr(args, args.tool)(args)

def dog(args):
  print 'Run something dog here'

def cat(args):
  print 'Run cat here'

def fish(args):
  print 'Yes run fish here'

print "Bye !"
```

Thanks, for your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EvenLisle's answer gives the correct idea, but you can easily generalize it by using `arg.tools` as the key to `globals()`.  Moreover, to simplify validation, you can use the `choices` argument of `add_argument` so that you know the possible values of `args.tool`.  If someone provides an argument other than dog, cat, or fish for the -t command line option, your parser will automatically notify them of the usage error.  Thus, your code would become:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(str(sys.argv[0]))
parser.add_argument('-t', '--tool', help='Input tool name.', required=True, 
                    choices=["dog","cat","fish"])
args = parser.parse_args()

def dog(args):
  print 'Run something dog here'

def cat(args):
  print 'Run cat here'

def fish(args):
  print 'Yes run fish here'

if callable(globals().get(args.tool)):
    globals()[args.tool](args)
```

Comment: thank you but i get this error getattr(args, args.tool)(args)
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'dog'

Comment: Look at my revised code above.  It doesn't use getattr() anywhere.  It's a different approach based on EvenLisle's.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
def cat(args):
  print 'Run cat here'

if "cat" in globals():
  globals()["cat"]("arg")
```

will print "Run cat here". You should consider making a habit of having your function definitions at the top of your file. Otherwise, the above snippet would not have worked, as your function `cat` would not yet be in the dictionary returned by `globals()`.

Comment: is it possible to add simple call function after print "Available" ? which will point to function. so i don't need to add if blabla in globals after each functions. thanks